# Mapping a MARC file

Tags: marc

I have a marc file X.rec and I need to map which headers it contains (issn, main title, alternative title, publisher, etc...).
Is there a simple way/tool that parse the file and output which headers it contains?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

There are a [variety of tools](http://wiki.code4lib.org/index.php/Working_with_MARC) that you can use to parse MARC data, depending on if you prefer a simple GUI application or want to include it into a specific script.

A couple of specific options:

- [MARCEdit](http://marcedit.reeset.net/) is a GUI application for Windows, but will run on Mac OS X and Linux using Mono.
- [ruby-marc](https://github.com/ruby-marc/ruby-marc) is a Ruby library to parse MARC records.
- [MARC/Perl](http://marcpm.sourceforge.net/) is a comprehensive suite of Perl modules for parsing MARC data.